# Using T-SQL, how do I substitute multiple variables in a procedure? Example provided

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Complete newbie here, so forgive me for any issues you may find.

I am using SQL Server 2012 and am looking into create procedure which will allow me to plug in different variables which will then update different database table columns, as well as update/setting some data in a different table as well.

Background is that our data source often updates random columns without notifying us - this may include column names or the data itself within them.

This is my sample query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EDIT_COLUMN_TYPE 
    @COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(200),
    @DATA_TYPE VARCHAR(200),
    @STRING_LENGTH VARCHAR(10),
    @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(200)
AS 
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Database.Schema.CONCAT('STG_'@TABLE_NAME) 
        ALTER COLUMN @COLUMN_NAME @DATA_TYPE (@STRING_LENGTH) NULL;

    ALTER TABLE Database.Schema.CONCAT('ARC_'@TABLE_NAME) 
        ALTER COLUMN @COLUMN_NAME @DATA_TYPE (@STRING_LENGTH) NULL;

    ALTER TABLE Database.Schema.@TABLE_NAME 
        ALTER COLUMN @COLUMN_NAME @DATA_TYPE (@STRING_LENGTH) NULL;

    UPDATE Database.Schema.PRE_SET_TABLE_HERE 
    SET DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR' 
    WHERE @COLUMN_NAME = 'COLUMN_NAME_HERE';
```

Comment: Can you clarify this part "plug in different variables which will then update different database table columns, as well as update/setting some data in a different table as well"?

Comment: Hi there, apologies - picked up that lingo from my colleague. I just mean to substitute in different names e.g. different table names - Customer, Supplier so it applies to the alter table part above as well as the update/set part.

Answer (score 0):

Build your `TSQL` as strings then run `exec`

```
declare @strsql varchar(max)

set @strsql = 'ALTER TABLE Database.Schema.CONCAT(''STG_'''+@TABLE_NAME+') ALTER COLUMN '+@COLUMN_NAME+' '+@DATA_TYPE+' ('+@STRING_LENGTH+') NULL;'

exec @strsql
```

Comment: I am not really certain, but that seems prone to SQL injection.

Comment: Is it possible to have a single version which I can simply just substitute in the different values automatically? Thank you